# hover over image thumb to reveal floating slideshow like on hotels.com

Tags: jquery, mootools, slideshow

On hotels.com when you hover over a hotel listing's image thumbnail a small floating slideshow pops up sliding through multiple images of the hotel. Can anyone point me to a Mootools or Jquery script that does this? thanks for any ideas.

---

Example link: 
http://www.hotels.com/de1475774/hotels-maui-island-hawaii/

---

I ended up posting this as a project to guru.com and titled it hotels.com style thumb hover slidshow. Paying $250 to $500 to sort it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.cycle is a good slideshow plugin but you'd need to initiate the effect with additional script to display and start on hover

[very VERY basic demo](http://jsbin.com/ajaqa3/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at jQuery Cycle plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/